# Error while running Azure Machine Learning web service but the experiment works fine

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created the Azure ML experiment with R script module 
it works fine while we run the experiment but
 when we publish the web service it throws error http 500 
 ( I believe the error is causing in the R script module because other modules are running fine in web service but i can't debug the problem

> Http status code: 500, Timestamp: Fri, 08 May 2015 04:23:14 GMT

Also is there any limitation in r e.g. some function which wont work in web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was facing this error because the R module in the Azure ML was was taking variable as the other data type and not producing any outputs results which i was checking through for loop which is why i was getting this error.